# Initial value Problem ODE not understanding solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$$x = c_1\cos (t) + c_2\sin (t)
$$
is a two-parameter
family of solutions of the second-order DE $$x'' + x = 0.
$$

Find
a solution of the second-order IVP consisting of this differential
equation and the given initial conditions:

$$x\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{2}
$$

and

$$x'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 0
$$

I found that:

$$x'(t) =  - c_1\sin (t) + c_2\cos (t)
$$

and then I solved for $c_2$

$$c_2 = 1 - c_1\sqrt 3 
$$

and plugged $c_2$ into $$x'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 0
$$

where

$$x'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) =  - c_1\sin (t) + (1 - c_1\sqrt 3 )\cos (t) = 0
$$

and
$$ = \frac{1}{2}c_1 + 1 - c_1\frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2} = 0
$$

and finally got as far as

$$c_1 = \frac{{(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2})}}{{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}}} = \frac{{ - 1}}{{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}}} = 
$$

However the book's solutions guide came up with

$$c_1 = \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{4},c_2 = \frac{1}{4}
$$

from

$$\frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}c_1 + \frac{1}{2}c_2 = \frac{1}{2}
$$

and

$$ - \frac{1}{2}c_1 + \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}c_2 = 0
$$

I just can't follow their logic, So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the equations
$$
x'\left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right) = 0 \tag1
$$
and
$$
x'(t) =  - c_1\sin (t) + c_2\cos (t) \tag2
$$
you can set $t = \frac\pi6$ (which I assume is what you did) so that
$x'(t)=0,$ $\sin (t)=\frac12,$ and $\cos (t) = \frac{\sqrt3}2,$
and plugging these values into Equation $(2)$ you would get
$$
0 = -c_1 \cdot \frac12 + c_2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}2. \tag3
$$
Solving Equation $(3)$ for $c_2$ in terms of $c_1,$ your first step might be to bring
$c_1$ to the left hand side, so that
$$
c_1 \cdot \frac12 = c_2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}2.
$$
and then multiply by $\frac2{\sqrt3}$ on both sides to get
$$
\frac1{\sqrt3} c_1 = c_2. \tag4
$$

Once you have $c_2$ in terms of $c_1$ (or vice versa) you still have to use the fact that $x\left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right) = \frac12,$ of course.

---

Actually it was unclear what you meant by "then I solved for $c_2$".
I assumed you meant you solved the immediately preceding equation with $x'(t),$ but if you meant that you went all the way back to the first equation you wrote and solved that at $t = \frac\pi6,$ you would get
$$
\frac12 = c_1 \frac{\sqrt3}2 \cdot  + c_2 \cdot \frac12. \tag5
$$
And now if you solve for $c_2$ you do indeed get $c_2 = 1 - c_1 \sqrt3.$
But in the subsequent steps you should have found that when $t = \frac\pi6,$
\begin{align}
0 &= - c_1\sin(t) + (1 - c_1\sqrt3)\cos(t)  \\
&= -c_1\cdot\frac12 + (1 - c_1\sqrt3)\cdot \frac{\sqrt3}2 \\
&= -\frac12 c_1 + \frac{\sqrt3}2 - \frac32 c_1 \\
&= \frac{\sqrt3}2 - 2 c_1,
\end{align}
and that is how we end up with $c_1 = \frac{\sqrt3}4.$

---

Now for what the book's author(s) apparently did: they derived Equation $(5)$
using the same method I described above, except that they wrote the
equation in the form
$$\frac{\sqrt3}2 c_1 + \frac12 c_2 = \frac12. \tag6$$
Then they derived Equation $(3)$ just as I did above,
except they wrote it
$$ - \frac12 c_1 + \frac{\sqrt3}2 c_2 = 0. \tag7$$
Now Equations $(6)$ and $(7)$ are two linear equations in two unknowns and there are standard methods (which you should study if you don't know them already) for solving such a set of equations.
For example, multiply both sides of Equation $(7)$ by $\sqrt3$ so that when you add the left side of Equation $(7)$ to the left side of Equation $(6)$
the terms in $c_1$ cancel and you're left with $2c_2$;
while adding the right-hand sides of these equations gives you $\frac12,$
so you conclude that
$$2c_2 = \frac12$$
and therefore $c_2 = \frac14.$ Plug that into either equation and solve for
$c_1.$
Of course if you notice that Equation $(7)$ has no constant term,
you may see that it immediately gives  you $c_1 = (\sqrt3)c_2,$
which you can plug into Equation $(6)$ to solve for $c_2.$

---

A word of advice: lay out your steps much more carefully and methodically and be very clear about what you're doing and why at each step.
Whoever grades your papers will appreciate it.

Comment: Thankyou for the insight and help with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Given that $x=c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t$ which are the family of solutions.

Finding the first derivative of the solution

$$x^{\prime}=-c_1\sin t+c_2\cos t$$

Now Substitute the initial condition of $x\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)=\dfrac12$

$$\dfrac12=c_1\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)+c_2\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
$$\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}c_1+\dfrac12c_2=\dfrac12\tag1$$

Now Substitute the initial condition of $x^\prime\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)=0$
$$0=-c_1\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)+c_2\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
$$-\dfrac12c_1+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}c_2=0\tag2$$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find the following values for $c_1$ and $c_2$
$$c_1=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{4},\ \ c_2=\dfrac12$$

Therefore the solution is $x=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{4}\cos t+\dfrac12\sin t$

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: @HappyHiggs If you find the answer helpful then accept the answer $\checkmark$ :)